# Using tethered Android phone as an internet gateway in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet, android, tethering

Using Android as a tethered USB gateway works fine in W7 but other devices (VirtualBox and Netbook via wireless hub) cannot acess the internet.

Can this be done and how?

Comment: When connecting the Android phone - Windows 7 pops a alert message in the notification are showing a NDIS device connected, and uses that for connecting to the internet. This device can be shared but request from other computers do not seem to be routed to via this connection.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your phone tethering connected with your laptop via USB cable, you can download an application called Connectify to make your laptop an Access Point broadcasting with your Wireless NIC. To do this on a desktop PC you need a wireless NIC on it.

Once you have your Connectify properly configured you can access the Internet from other computer and devices via Wireless connection.

Comment: Connectify will just open a shared wifi access point on your windows device. This is known as a "Wireless Hosted Network". You can learn how to do this yourself without using a program here: http://superuser.com/a/1122786/109803

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Wireless Tether?

Start tethering. W7 has wifi access and shares access with VM. Then Netbook also has wifi access.

Comment: If you are reading this in 2016, this solution is not maintained and no longer works for android v5 and above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your VMs on the same private network as your windoze box then create that network if not there and configure your VM to allow network connectivity.

If you do not care if your VMs or on a private network with eachother exclusively then just join the same WiFi network from your Android device in your VMs (be sure to give them WiFi cards).

If you are tethering physically (ie USB) then the former is the easier path